# Add ArrayList to a SQL Database? (FILE MANAGEMENT)

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I'm doing a college assignment for my data structures programming class. We're working in groups for this assignment, so I'm currently working off one of my teammates projects. I added local READ/WRITE code so I can save the arraylist to a local .dat file. However, for extra marks, I can do advanced file handling.

I have decided to do a MySQL approach.

The program is a basketball player CRUD system, where you can add a player, what team they're on, address, name, and number.

I have 5 classes. A coach class(which currently doesn't do anything), a player class and a team class. These classes only have set, get and toString methods.

The last 2 classes is the BasketBallSystem class which has all the GUI, methods, menus, etc.

```
package ie.wit.basketball;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class BasketballSystem {

public ArrayList<Team> getTeams() {
    return teams;
}

private ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();

public BasketballSystem() throws Exception {
    teams=BasketballFile.ArrayListFromFile();
    if (teams.size() == 0)
    {       Team t = new Team("Golden State Warriors", 10);
    teams.add(t);

    t.getPlayers().add(new Player("Donna Kinsella", 666));
    t.getPlayers().add(new Player("Tommy White", 21));

    t.setTheCoach(new Coach("Tom Jones"));

    for (Player p : t.getPlayers()) {
        System.out.println(p.getPlayerName());
    }

    t = new Team("Florida Falcons", 10);
    t.getPlayers().add(new Player("Don Keating", 76));
    t.getPlayers().add(new Player("Tom Green", 22));
    teams.add(t);
    }

}

public int menuMain() {

    JLabel addPlayer = new JLabel("1. Add a Player");
    JLabel listPlayers = new JLabel("2. List all Players");
    JLabel updateDetails = new JLabel("3. Update Players Details");
    JLabel deletePlayers = new JLabel("4. Delete a player");
    JLabel exitSys = new JLabel("5. Exit");
    JTextField optionField = new JTextField();

    Object[] message = new Object[6];

    message[0] = addPlayer;
    message[1] = listPlayers;
    message[2] = updateDetails;
    message[3] = deletePlayers;
    message[4] = exitSys;
    message[5] = optionField;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    try{
    return Integer.parseInt(optionField.getText());
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // new BasketballSystem();

    int choice;

    BasketballSystem b = new BasketballSystem();

    do {

        choice = b.menuMain();

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            b.addPlayer();
            break;
        case 2:
            b.listPlayers();
            break;
        case 3:
            b.updatePlayersDetails();
            break;
        case 4:
            b.removePlayer();
            break;
        case 5:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for using this system.");
            BasketballFile.ArrayListToFile(b.getTeams());
            break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry, Please try again.");
        }
    } while (choice != 5);

}

private void updatePlayersDetails() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String playerNumber = new String("Player Number");
    JTextField number = new JTextField("");
    String playerName = new String("Player Name");
    JTextField name = new JTextField("");
    String playerAddress = new String("Player Address");
    JTextField address = new JTextField("");

    String[] teamnames = new String[teams.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++)
        teamnames[i] = teams.get(i).getTeamName();
    JComboBox<String> teamnamescombo = new JComboBox<String>(teamnames);

    Object message[] = new Object[6];

    message[0] = playerNumber;
    message[1] = number;
    message[2] = playerName;
    message[3] = name;
    message[4] = playerAddress;
    message[5] = address;

    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Player Details Update",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    if (response == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        try {
            int pnum = Integer.parseInt(number.getText());
            List<Player> players = teams.get(teamnamescombo.getSelectedIndex()).getPlayers();
            Iterator<Player> it = players.iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Player p = it.next();
                if (p.getPlayerNumber() == pnum) {
                    p.setPlayerName(playerName);
                    p.setPlayerNumber(playerNumber);
                    p.setPlayerName(playerName);
                }
                // if (p.getPlayerAddress()==pAdd){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player's address has been successfully updated");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Player number invalid");
        }
    }
}

private void removePlayer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String playerNumber = new String("Player Number");
    JTextField number = new JTextField("");

    String[] teamnames = new String[teams.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++)
        teamnames[i] = teams.get(i).getTeamName();
    JComboBox<String> teamnamescombo = new JComboBox<String>(teamnames);

    Object message[] = new Object[3];

    message[0] = playerNumber;
    message[1] = number;
    message[2] = teamnamescombo;

    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Player Removal", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    if (response == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

        int pnum = Integer.parseInt(number.getText());
        List<Player> players = teams.get(teamnamescombo.getSelectedIndex()).getPlayers();
        Iterator<Player> it = players.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Player p = it.next();
            if (p.getPlayerNumber() == pnum) {
                it.remove();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player has been successfully removed");
            }
        }
    }

}

private void listPlayers() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // String

    for (Team t : teams) // for all teams
    {

        System.out.println("Team: " + t.getTeamName());
        for (Player p : t.getPlayers()) // for all player
        {
            System.out.println(
                    "Player: " + p.getPlayerName() + " " + p.getPlayerNumber() + " " + p.getPlayerAddress());

        }
    }
}

private void addPlayer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // String teamName
    String playerName = new String("Player name");
    String playerNumber = new String("Player Number");
    String playerAddress = new String("Player Address");
    JTextField name = new JTextField("");
    JTextField number = new JTextField("");
    JTextField address = new JTextField("");

    String[] teamnames = new String[teams.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++)
        teamnames[i] = teams.get(i).getTeamName();
    JComboBox<String> teamnamescombo = new JComboBox<String>(teamnames);

    Object message[] = new Object[7];

    message[0] = playerName;
    message[1] = name;
    message[2] = playerNumber;
    message[3] = number;
    message[4] = playerAddress;
    message[5] = address;
    message[6] = teamnamescombo;

    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Player Entry", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    if (response == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {


        int pnum = Integer.parseInt(number.getText());
        Player newPlay = new Player(name.getText(), pnum);
        teams.get(teamnamescombo.getSelectedIndex()).getPlayers().add(newPlay);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player has been successfully Added");
    }   
        {

        }
        }



}
```

The last class is the BasketBallFile class, which handles the file management.

```
package ie.wit.basketball;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BasketballFile {

public static void ArrayListToFile(ArrayList<Team> al) throws Exception {


    try{
        File f=new File("mydata.dat");
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(al);

        System.out.println("Written to file!");
        oos.close();
        fos.close();

    }catch(Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }


}

public static ArrayList<Team> ArrayListFromFile() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Team> al=new ArrayList<Team>();

    try{
        File f=new File("mydata.dat");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        al=(ArrayList<Team>)ois.readObject();

        System.out.println("Read from file!");
        ois.close();
        fis.close();

    }catch(Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());

    }

    return al;

}


}
```

I dont expect you to tell me exactly how to do it, I just dont know where to start. I tried googling this already, and I tried searching tutorials but everything I tried didn't work. My Java knowledge is very basic, so if you can help at all, that would be great. Thank you.

Sorry if I didnt get the formatting right too, its my first time using this website. thank you!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, and it seems an answer would be very broad. If you have a specific problem with the code you posted, can you be more specific about where? If you are just looking for pointers on where to find help on how to go about this, then that is normally considered off-topic for SO, see "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book" in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). More help on asking can be found in the links [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

The key to database management in Java is the [Java Persistence API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API). It's quite a huge topic, and personally I only know it from the context of Java EE, but [it also works with Java SE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html).

With only a basic Java knowledge this could be a huge leap, maybe you should get a good understanding of relational databases and how to use them before jumping into the wonderful world of ORM. For extra marks in a college assignment I would probably just turn the read/write into random file access instead of serializing the entire list together into the file. (Which also isn't easy but it doesn't need you to learn new concepts.)